# How does the Belkin OmniView Remote IP Manager (IP KVM) do Hard Reboots?

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse, power-distribution-unit, power-supply-unit

I am looking to get an IP KVM for a single server.

The features tab on http://catalog.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=291011 shows that the OmniView Remote IP Manager can do hard reboots i.e.:

- Supports serial devices such as PDUs, to perform hard reboots remotely

Would it be able to hard reboot a standard PC or server with a standard PSU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That KVM talks to Power Distribution Units, essentially power strips (or outright circuit breaker cabinets) with brains. The hard reboot is accomplished by dropping power from the power outlet (or circuit in the case of circuit based PDU's). You can do this with standard power supply units so long as you attach them to a power strip that supports serial shutdown commands.